# Arquillian embedded tomcat7 unfortunately includes the whole classpath

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

For my arquillian tests I created a WebArchive using ShrinkWrap which only includes classes which are necessary for the integrationtest.

I use **embedded-tomcat7** as container adapter and start the test via maven. Unfortunately the classpath contains all classes of my project (because maven sets it so).

Can I configure (arquillian.xml) to use an other classloader or so?

Comment: I tried to exclude some dependencies from the classpath in maven failsafe-plugin. <classpathDependencyExcludes>      <classpathDependencyExclude>XXX:XXX</classpathDependencyExclude>    </classpathDependencyExcludes> The problem is, that this has no effect. I CAN set the classpath in the surefire-plugin but this unfortunately also sets the classpath for component tests. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results after some days of search:

Don't use an embedded container if you really want to control your classpath.